# Preconditions and postconditions

Tags: programming-languages

What are preconditions and postconditions in this C++ function?

I have this example in my slides but still didn't get the idea!

```
*Comment function declaration:
    void showInterest(double balance, double rate);
    //Precondition: balance is nonnegative account balance
    //      rate is interest rate as percentage
    //Postcondition: amount of interest on given balance,
   //       at given rate …
*Often called Inputs & Outputs
```

Comment: This is not really specific to any particular programming language.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition

Answer (score 2):

*Preconditions* and *postconditions* are just ways to describe a function in more detail, and give some hints on how you can use this function or what to expect from it.

*Preconditions* are conditions that have to hold *before* (*pre* is Latin for *before*) the function gets called by a user. These are usually conditions about the parameter. E.g. a simple precondition for the function `square_root(x)` might be: `x` has to be non-negative. Because the function cannot handle negative numbers, maybe even crashes, or just return wrong values. But there are even other preconditions. Other preconditions could involve global states, or the state of objects. E.g. before you call this function you need to call another. So the user has to make sure, that all the conditions are satisfied, before he calls the method.

*Postconditions* are about *after* the call (again, Latin). That can mean the return value of the function, or the global state of the program or object after calling the function. This are conditions a user can expect from the program. It is kinda like a guarantee, if a user calls the function in a way that satisfies all preconditions, then he will get something that is described in the postconditions.

Answer (score 1):

Preconditions and postconditions specify the semantics of the function; a contract which the function fulfills.

Using your function as an example, here is what the preconditions and postconditions mean:

> **If** `balance` is a non-negative account balance and `rate` is an interest rate given as percentage, **then** `showInterest` will show the amount of interest on the given balance at the given rate.

The author of the slides is being a bit sloppy, since the postconditions mentions "amount of interest" without mentioning its relevance. Given the name of the procedure, it is probably being shown; but otherwise, I would have guessed that it is a value being returned (though your function returns no value).

If `balance` is negative, then the behavior of the procedure is undefined. A function is only promised to fulfill its postconditions if the preconditions are fulfilled when the function is called.